# Why does the Kerberos protocol not feature perfect forward secrecy?

Tags: security, networking, encryption, cryptography, kerberos

Why does the Kerberos protocol not feature [perfect forward secrecy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_forward_secrecy)?

Answer (score 6):

The [technical reason](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4120#section-10) is as follows:

> The Kerberos protocol in its basic
> form does not provide perfect
> forward secrecy for communications.
> If traffic has been recorded by    an
> eavesdropper, then messages encrypted
> using the KRB_PRIV message,    or
> messages encrypted using
> application-specific encryption under
> keys exchanged using Kerberos can be
> decrypted if the user's,
> application server's, or KDC's key is
> subsequently discovered.  This    is
> because the session key used to
> encrypt such messages, when
> transmitted over the network, is
> encrypted in the key of the
> application server.  It is also
> encrypted under the session key from
> the user's TGT when it is returned to
> the user in the KRB_TGS_REP
> message.  The session key from the TGT
> is sent to the user in the
> KRB_AS_REP message encrypted in the
> user's secret key and embedded in
> the TGT, which was encrypted in the
> key of the KDC.  Applications
> requiring perfect forward secrecy must
> exchange keys through    mechanisms
> that provide such assurance, but may
> use Kerberos for    authentication of
> the encrypted channel established
> through such    other means.

Basically perfect forward secrecy adds additional overhead to the protocol that is not necessary for many of its applications.  If you need PFS, then you can add it.  What does matter to most Kerberos users is speed. If you have tens of thousends of employes all over the world all authenticated at the same time, then the overhead required for PFS is going to be too expensive and there for not practical.